# BASH Script Using & in a function

Tags: bash

Trying to execute a function with an `&` so the For Loop will continue to execute without waiting for the job to be done.

My Function

```
perform_hdparm() {
hdparm -t "$1" | awk '/seconds/{print $11}'}
```

The For Loop

```
for drive in ${hddletter[@]}; do
printf '%s: %s\n' "$drive" "$(perform_hdparm "$drive")"
```

The Array contains

```
/dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdk
```

So where do I put the `&` at to make things continue or can I? Just trying to speed things up.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it after the command you want to run in the background:

```
for drive in "${hddletter[@]}"
do
  printf '%s: %s\n' "$drive" "$(perform_hdparm "$drive")" &
done
wait
```

Comment: Nice, I was putting it in the function area which didn't work... Anyways this works and I just tested it.